# How can record calls in Android 12 and 13 or in higher versions?

Tags: android, kotlin

My AIM is to record the call for Android 10 higher versions.

My approach:

- I am using InCallService and MediaRecorder,
- the Media Recorder works properly for normal cases,
- but when I am placing the call, the blank file created without audio

I know google restricted the call recording in latest versions.

but I want to know how google Phone app and TrueCaller is doing these things.

It would be great if someone could help me out with them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.